# Update deadlock issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL server 2005 and running into deadlock issues.  I've begun reading up on NO LOCK, but I'm not sure that is the correct way to solve my problem.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have a batch process that is running every 15 seconds.  It generates dynamic UPDATE SQL statements based off a list of foreign keys.  To over simplify, imagine the below simple SQL statement:

```
UPDATE dual
SET val1 = @val1
WHERE fk = @fk
;
```

Remember this example is over simplified, for each foreign key the SQL statement is actually different, but the table it updates and the values are always the same.  I cannot just write a single update statement to deal with all the foreign keys at once.

If I run each statement one at a time everything works fine, but I risk going over my 15 second interval.  As a silver bullet, I decided to multi thread the batch application so it would run 25 update statements at once instead of just 1 at a time.  After doing this, I begin receiving deadlock errors.

How do I solve this deadlock issue?  Three things to remember:

1. The batch is the only application that will ever INSERT, UPDATE, or
   DELETE records from the table in question
2. Every UPDATE statement uses the foreign key in the WHERE clause, so
   the batch would never access the same record at once
3. If a record gets bad data, the batch would self correct it in the
   next run

Comment: Your 3 things to remember:  #1 seems unlikely.  I bet there's another process somewhere that participating in the deadlock.  If you could capture a deadlock graph, it will be extremely helpful to point you in the right direction.  [Creating a SQL Server Agent Alert by Using the WMI Provider for Server Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186385(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: How many rows are being updated by each update statement being run? Over 5000? I assume all "FK" columns are indexed?

Comment: Post the execution plan of a representative UPDATE and a deadlock graph.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your current setup, within your dynamic sql create a table variable and insert your values into it.  This will all be inserts so you should not have to worry about deadlocks.  Next update your table(s) with a single update by joining your table variable to your real table.  This way you are only hitting your actual table with one single update statement.